# Vulkan CommandBuffer in use after vkDeviceWait Idle

Tags: c++, c, vulkan

During initialization of my program I want to use some single time command buffers for image layout transitions and acceleration structure building etc.

However, I can't seem to free the command buffer once it's finished.

```cpp
VkCommandBuffer AppContext::singleTimeCommandBuffer() const {
    VkCommandBuffer ret;
    auto allocInfo = vks::initializers::commandBufferAllocateInfo(vkCommandPool, VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY, 1);
    vkCheck(vkAllocateCommandBuffers(vkDevice, &allocInfo, &ret));
    auto beginInfo = vks::initializers::commandBufferBeginInfo();
    beginInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT;
    vkCheck(vkBeginCommandBuffer(ret, &beginInfo));
    return ret;
}

void AppContext::endSingleTimeCommands(VkCommandBuffer cmdBuffer) const {
    vkCheck(vkEndCommandBuffer(cmdBuffer));
    auto submitInfo = vks::initializers::submitInfo(&cmdBuffer);
    vkQueueSubmit(queues.graphics, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);

    vkQueueWaitIdle(queues.graphics);
    // Overkill, I know
    vkDeviceWaitIdle(vkDevice);
    vkFreeCommandBuffers(vkDevice, vkCommandPool, 1, &cmdBuffer);
}
```

Which produces the following validation error:

```
VUID-vkFreeCommandBuffers-pCommandBuffers-00047(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 448332540 - Validation Error: [ VUID-vkFreeCommandBuffers-pCommandBuffers-00047 ] Object 0: handle = 0x5586acaeff78, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; | MessageID = 0x1ab902fc | Attempt to free VkCommandBuffer 0x5586acaeff78[] which is in use. The Vulkan spec states: All elements of pCommandBuffers must not be in the pending state (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.182.0/linux/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkFreeCommandBuffers-pCommandBuffers-00047)
    Objects: 1
        [0] 0x5586acaeff78, type: 6, name: NULL
```

I don't see how this makes sense since the VkQueueWaitIdle as well as the vkDeviceWaitIdle should ensure the command buffer to not be in the pending state. Am I misunderstanding the Vulkan specs or might I have stumbled upon a bug in the video driver, or perhaps the validation layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't checking the return values of vkQueueSubmit(), vkQueueWaitIdle() or vkDeviceWaitIdle(). Are any of them failing? That could cause this error.

Comment: Great suggestion, you were correct. They return VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST. It would appear that I'm doing some undefined stuff when building acceleration structures. Thanks so much, I think that answers this question <3